# How do I refresh connected fragments accordingly?

Tags: android

I'm making a simple notepad app. In one fragment there's a list view of added notes and when some note is selected the other fragment shows the details of that note. Now if user clicks delete button a note is deleted, but how do I refresh the list view and detail view accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For refreshing the `ListView` actually what you have to refresh is the underlaying `Adapter`.

This would be the workflow of your scenario:

1. Remove the selected item
2. Call [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)
3. Set another item as the current one, for example the previous note or the first one.

And that's it.